# Plot of falling body

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, animation

I'm new into Mathematica and I need to help with animated plot of falling body:

Including mass of the body and the force of air resistance $F = -k*v(t)$, slowing down the body with positive contant k, we get the following problem:

$y(0)=0,\\ y'(0)=v_0,\\ y''(t)+\frac{k}{m} y'(t)=g.$

I need to create function with arguments: initial height, initial speed, mass of the body, resistance coefficient.

Comment: There is a very good discussion of external ballistics by Jon McLoone [here](https://blog.wolfram.com/author/jon-mcloone/do-computers-dumb-down-math-education/). Your problem is a special case of what he discusses

Answer (score 6):

> I need to help with animated plot of falling body:

I get this nostalgic feeling that I've seen similar question before in this forum.

But one possible way to do this, is to just write the solution of the ODE directly in Manipulate, and then adjust the solution based on sliders. Something like the following

[image]

```
Manipulate[

 Module[{sol, k0, m0, v0, g = 9.81},
  (*this below is solution to y''+k/my'=g. with y(0)=0,y'(0)=v0. Done offline*)
  sol = -((
    E^(-((k0 t)/m0))
      m0 (g m0 - E^((k0 t)/m0) g m0 + E^((k0 t)/m0) g k0 t - k0 v0 + 
       E^((k0 t)/m0) k0 v0))/k0^2);

  Plot[sol /. {k0 -> k, m0 -> m, v0 -> initialV}, {t, 0, maxTime},
   AxesLabel -> {"t", "y(t)"}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-15, 0}},
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
   PlotStyle -> Red, BaseStyle -> 12]
  ]
 ,
 {{maxTime, .01, "time?"}, .01, 2, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{initialV, 0, "Initial velocity?"}, 0, 10, .01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k, 1, "k?"}, 1, 10, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m, 1, "m?"}, 1, 10, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {maxTime, initialV, k, m}
 ]
```

The above can be improved more if needed.